# Which is faster, Convert.ToXX() or xx.Parse(yy.ToString())?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a method faster. Right now, it takes an `object obj` and converts it to a double with the following:

```
double val = Convert.ToDouble(obj);
```

Would it be faster if I did this?

```
double val = double.Parse(obj.ToString());
```

Comment: Why don't you profile it?  In fact, using a profiler might show that you're looking for speedup in completely the wrong places.

Comment: I don't think they do the same thing.

Comment: If you were to use `Parse` I would potentially use `TryParse` in order to handle potential converstion problems (unless the checking is doing outside the scope of suggested code)

Comment: Why not make the method take a double as argument and get rid of the boxing?

Comment: `double.Parse(obj.ToString());` can cause a `NullReferenceExcpetion` when `obj` is null wheras `Convert.ToDouble(obj)` would return 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `string` `Convert.ToDouble` just checks value for `null` and return `0.0` if so. Then it really calls `double.Parse`:

```
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public static double ToDouble(object value)
{
  if (value != null)
    return ((IConvertible) value).ToDouble((IFormatProvider) null);
  else
    return 0.0;
}

// common implementation of IConvertable
double IConvertible.ToDouble(IFormatProvider provider)
{
  return Convert.ToDouble(this, provider);
}

// implementation for string
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public static double ToDouble(string value, IFormatProvider provider)
{
  if (value == null)
    return 0.0;
  else
    return double.Parse(value, NumberStyles.Float | NumberStyles.AllowThousands, provider);
}

// and for long. differs, right? 
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public static double ToDouble(long value)
{
  return (double) value;
}
```

So I don't think that `double.Parse` if much faster for non-number types. But when you don't really know that type your argument is, it's better to call `Convert.ToDouble(value)` instead of `double.Parse(value.ToString())`.

Comment: `But when you don't really know that type your argument is, it's better to call Convert.ToDouble(value) instead of double.Parse(value.ToString()).`  You shouldn't ever *be* in the position where you don't know what they type is.  You should know that the object is a string, or a double, or an int, or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

`Convert.ToDouble()` actually wraps a `double.Parse()` call so the difference in speed is negligible.

Comment: Note that the OP is comparing `Convert.ToDouble(object)` with `Double.Parse(string)`. `Convert.ToDouble(object)` doesn't wrap `Double.Parse`, it casts the object to `IConvertible` and calls `ToDouble()`.

Answer (score -1):

In theory the first, as you're making a single call. The second example you're calling the Parse method and then passing it the result of the ToString method.

That being said, see some of the comments as to why there maybe better solutions (i.e. what if it fails).

Comment: If you're going to take the time to write an answer you really shouldn't just be saying, "read the comments for the real solutions".

Comment: @Servy I was answering the question he asked, not expanding it to how he should be doing something. The other comments already handled that aspect.

Comment: Then either don't mention the other comments, or actually discuss them with enough depth that he doesn't need to go elsewhere read them as they're quoted in your answer.  I much prefer the later.